# How to detect incoming video call from from ZegoCloud when app is closed or when chat activity is destroyed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, zegocloud

I'm trying to use ZegoCloud to add audio & video call features, and it's working fine while the sender and receiver are in the same activity (Chat Activity). But, when the receiver is on another activity, the app in background or the app is closed, the incoming call is never detected and the incoming call activity is never shown. Below is the android manifest with incoming call service.

Thank you..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="com.appeaser.imagetransitionlibrary" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" /> <!-- Gal -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> <!-- For Android 12 and above devices, the following permission is also required. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" /> <!-- W -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".gal.ImageEditActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppThemeBack">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ProfileManageActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ChatActivity"
            android:exported="false" /> <!--  -->
        <activity
            android:name=".contactLibrary.core.ContactPickerActivity"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".myCont.multiPickerC.MultiContactPickerActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".myCont.MyContActivity"
            android:exported="false" />

        <profileable android:shell="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".zegInvi.callwithinvitation.call.IncomingCallDialog"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/dialogActivityTheme" />

        <service
            android:name=".zegInvi.callwithinvitation.call.CallBackgroundService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".zegInvi.callwithinvitation.call.CallingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zegInvi.callwithinvitation.call.CallWaitingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".zegInvi.callwithinvitation.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity android:name=".zegInvi.V"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I believe a push notification service like Firebase Cloud Messaging is required for that

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and leave a code sample.

Comment: Don't they have a working example in their repos? I have no experience with this sort of apps, may be worth a check https://github.com/ZEGOCLOUD

Comment: I'm already checking their examples, and they have a CallBackgroundService which i think is enough for that, but nothing has changed.